# Can't call method from another class

Tags: java, swing, class, methods

I have two classes.
The main one opens the second one in a jframe in which the user will press a button and trigger a method from the main class/jframe `editare(String value)` that will automatically add some data to some jtextfields in the main jframe.The problem is that it won't trigger the method.I tried calling other methods from the main class,it doesn't call them either.I tried a lot of stuff for like the past 1-2 hours,can't figure it out.

Here is some code :
From the second jframe :

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
Test2 test2=new Test2();
test2.citireser(list.getSelectedValue().toString()); //won't work.works if i call it from the same method,the main one
test2.restart(); //won't work either
this.dispose(); }
```

From the first jframe,the main one :

```
public void citireser(String cur) {
    try {
        serializedPath = "C:/Inter/" + cur;
        InputStream file = new FileInputStream(serializedPath);
        InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
        ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(buffer);

        String[] storeAllArraysREAD[] = (String[][]) input.readObject();
        prodr = storeAllArraysREAD[0];
        cantr = storeAllArraysREAD[1];
        pretr = storeAllArraysREAD[2];
        input.close();
        buffer.close();
        file.close();
       System.err.println("prodr[1]= "+prodr[1].toString());
        for (int m = 0; m < prodr.length - 1; m++) {

        allprod.get(m).setText(prodr[m]);
        allcant.get(m).setText(cantr[m]);
        allpret.get(m).setText(pretr[m]);
        produsnou();

    }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("EROARE");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
       System.err.println("EROARE");
    }

}
```

EDIT : Ok,after trying different stuff for a couple of hours i've got it.

```
public class Opt extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Printable {

private final Test2 main; 

public Opt(Test2 aMain) {
     main = aMain;
    try {

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    initComponents();
    jScrollPane2.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
    jScrollPane2.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);

    citirel();

    if (list.getModel().getSize() == 0) {
        jButton1.setEnabled(false);
        jButton2.setEnabled(false);
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help,i don't know who i should pick as the right answer :( Sorry to the other guy

Comment: for (int m = 0; m < prodr.length - 1; m++) { do you want the condition to be length-1? that will not travel through the whole array

Comment: I want to help you, but you need to share more code than this.

Comment: the `-1` is ok,the last one is an empty string.That is not the issue.I don't know what else to post in matters of code cuz i posted everything i find relevant.it just won't accept the reference to my first class or something

Comment: Also,can't really post the whole code as its like 2k lines in 2 classes.I know it's messy and a bad way but i'm learning while working on a big project but i'll take care of the cleanness of my code after i make my app do the things i need really bad.Sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct me if any of this is wrong, as I'm trying to understand your program from incomplete code:

1. `Test2` (a `JFrame` containing your program entry point `main(string[])`) at some point creates a second class (also a `JFrame`) and opens it.
2. When you click a certain button in your second window, you wish to modify some elements of the `Test2` window, and close the secondary window.

Assuming the above is correct, there is one obvious problem I can see in the code snippets you've posted.

In `jButton3ActionPerformed`, you're creating a *new* `Test2` object, and modifying that. If you want to modify the original window, you need to be storing a reference to it. For example, require a `Test2` object as a parameter to your second class, and store that parameter as a field in the class.

Comment: Yes,something like that.The first jframe and main class is an app for making shopping lists that you can save to files.You can click a button on the first jframe that will take you to a new window with a list that contains all the files saved.You can preview them there and if you wish,you can press a button that will get you back to the first and main window,will read the file you chose and will make it able for editting.Indeed,if i set `test2.setvisible(true)` it will open a new window that has what i need in it.How can i fix this ?

Comment: You need a reference to the original `Test2` object, instead of creating a new one. If your list window class has a field like `private Test2 main;` and has a constructor like `public ListWindow(Test2 main) { this.main = main; }` and you create the list window from `Test2` like `ListWindow list = new ListWindow(this);`, then `jButton3ActionPerformed` can call `main.citireser(...);`.

Comment: Well,my main class/jframe is now named `Main` and the second one is named `Opt`.The project name is `Test2`.How can i reference it and not create a new one ? I tried a couple of things after searching but nothing worked.I don't have a field like that nor any other stuff you pointed out :( Sorry for not being able to give the full code :(

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you're working with a new instance of `Test2`. In the action performed (first block of code), you're creating a new `Test2` (which would be the first frame). You have to keep somewhere (usually a field) the reference to the first `Test2` created.

If you're having further issues, consider editing your question and posting the full code (the two frames entirely, at least). My spider senses are telling me that there's some context missing.

*Also, we have similar family names. :-)*

Comment: Damn,saw your post too late.You might be right ! Also,yea,cool coincidence,heh